# Using partial application to compose functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an application that will provide notifications to clients. It has two configurations:

Default: A single web api instance that notifies the appropriate subscribers

Alternative: Under high load, there will be multiple web api instances. To coordinate messages between instances, I will leverage a redis backplane. When an api instance receives a message, it sends it to the redis backplane, which then pushes it back down to all api instances.

I have a `config.useRedis` option that should control whether Redis should be used. To get things working, I created some pretty monolithic code:

```
//Channels will reference the channel name - which is our device id - and an array
//of websockets that are interested in that device
let channels = {};
let redisSubscribers = [];

// Send a message to the appropriate websocket clients listening on the right channel
// As we check the channel, we'll do a little housekeeping as well
const broadcast = (data) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(data);
  const deviceId = message.deviceId;

  if (Object.keys(channels).some(key => +key === deviceId)) {
    //Perform a cleanup of any closed sockets
    channels[deviceId] = channels[deviceId].filter(socket => socket.readyState === 1);

    channels[deviceId].forEach(ws => ws.send(data));

    //If the channel is empty, nuke the channel and close the redis subscription
    //if appropriate
    if (channels[deviceId].length === 0) {
      delete channels[deviceId];

      if (config.useRedis) {
        const subscriber = redisSubscribers.find(sub => +sub.deviceId === deviceId);
        if(subscriber) {
          subscriber.quit();
          redisSubscribers = redisSubscribers.filter(sub => sub !== subscriber);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

...    

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('socket established...')
  const querystring = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true).query;
  const deviceId = querystring.deviceId;

  if (!Object.keys(channels).includes(deviceId)) {
    channels[deviceId] = [ws];

    if(config.useRedis) {
      //Init redis subscriber
      ...
    }
  }
  else {
    channels[deviceId].push(ws);
  }

  ws.on('message', (data) => {
    if(config.useRedis) {
      redisPublisher.publish(deviceId, data);
    }
    else {
      const message = JSON.parse(data);
      broadcast(message);
    }
  });
});
```

I'd like to compose the behaviour instead, which would provide more flexibility in future in case I want to move to something else besides Redis.

So, if `Redis` is enabled for the app, in the `broadcast` function, I want to enhance the function with additional logic. In the `connection` handler, I want to init a `Redis` subscriber to receive messages from the backplane. In the `message` handler, I want to replace the default publishing logic with the custom `Redis` logic.

Note: The following has not been tested, I just threw some code together to demonstrate the course. Consider it pseudo-code :)

**websocketserver.js**

```
const websocketServer = () => {
  let channels = {};
  const broadcast = (function(data) {
    return function(enhancement) {
      if (Object.keys(channels).some(key => +key === deviceId)) {
        //Perform a cleanup of any closed sockets
        channels[deviceId] = channels[deviceId].filter(socket => socket.readyState === 1);

        channels[deviceId].forEach(ws => ws.send(data));

        //If the channel is empty, nuke the channel
        if (channels[deviceId].length === 0) {
          delete channels[deviceId];
        }

        // If any "enhancement" should be applied, execute the passed in function
        if(typeof enhancement === 'function') {
          enhancement(deviceId)
        }
      }
    }
  })

  const onConnection = () => {
    return function(enhancedSubscribe, enhancedPublish) {
      console.log('socket established...')
      const querystring = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true).query;
      const deviceId = querystring.deviceId;

      if (!Object.keys(channels).includes(deviceId)) {
        channels[deviceId] = [ws];

        if(typeof === 'enhancedSubscribe') {
          enhancedSubscribe(deviceId)
        }
      }
      else {
        channels[deviceId].push(ws);
      }

      ws.on('message', (enhancedPublish) => {
        if(typeof enhancedPublish === 'function'){
          enhancedPublish(data);
        }
        else {
          const message = JSON.parse(data);
          broadcast(message);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    broadcast,
    onConnection,
    onMessage
  }
}
```

**redisServer.js**

```
const redisServer = () => {
  let redisSubscribers = [];

  const removeSubscriber = () => {
    const subscriber = redisSubscribers.find(sub => +sub.deviceId === deviceId);
    if(subscriber) {
      subscriber.quit();
      redisSubscribers = redisSubscribers.filter(sub => sub !== subscriber);
    }
  }

  const enhancedSubscribe = (deviceId, broadcast) => {
    //Init redis subscriber
    ...
  }

  const enhancedPublish = (deviceId, data) => {
    redisPublisher.publish(deviceId, data);
  }

  return {
    removeSubscriber,
    enhancedSubscribe,
    enhancedPublish
  }
}
```

I attempt to compose the behaviour I want like this:

**serverFactory.js**

```
const server = () => {

  const broadcast = (data) => {
    let webSocketBroadcast = websocketServer.broadcast(data);
    if (config.useRedis) {
      return webSocketBroadcast();
    }
    else{
      return webSocketBroadcast(redisServer.enchanceBroadcast);
    }
  }

  const onConnection = (ws) => {
    let websocketServerOnConnection = websocketServer.onConnection();
    if (config.useRedis) {
      retuen websocketServerOnConnection()
    }
    else
    }
  }

  return {
    broadcast,
    onconnection,
    onMessage
  }
}
```

So, I am attempting to extend/enhance the websocket behaviour with partial application. Does this make sense? Anything further I can do to improve this or make it more flexible?

Comment: What you're doing is interesting, but I'm not convinced it wouldn't be easier to achieve with classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically, FP thinking means we don't extend functionality, we **compose functionality**. In JavaScript, when we are  composing things usually we can use `bind` to specialize a function instead of having to write nested functions everywhere.

The composition is what affords us the greater flexibility in FP.

Here is [a good SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842026/principles-best-practices-and-design-patterns-for-functional-programming) about guiding principles of FP. And also [a good video series](https://youtu.be/BMUiFMZr7vk) that, although a little basic, does a good job of demonstrating FP concepts.

Here's my take on your FP psuedocode that gets at this subscription model with redis as a possible specialized task, I was *very judicious* in my functions. Normally wouldn't do this, it's a little over the top (every call to bind creates a new function, which can be a performance concern), but it's purely for demonstrative purposes:

```
/* CONFIG */
let useRedis = config.useRedis; // env var / conf file / whatever


// Figure out the most basic actions you need to do,
//  or the fundamental types that compose your problem

// most actions here surround subscriptions
//   - subscribe (add new channel)
//   - broadcast data to subscribers
//   - unsubscribe (delete)
//   - sendMsg (is what broadcast does)


let sendMsg = (msg, ws, id) => ws.send(msg);

// the redis vs non part is just implementation detail
if(useRedis) {
  sendMsg = (msg, redisPublisher, id) => redisPublisher.publish(id, msg);
}

let broadcast = (sendMsgFunc, id, msg, ws) => {
  let sendCurrMsg = sendMsgFunc.bind(null, msg, ws);
  // maybe this array could be array of ws or redis...? up to you! :D
  channels[id].forEach(sendCurrMsg);
}

let unsubscribe = (id, channels) => {
  delete channels[id];
  return channels;
}

let findRedisSub = (id, s) => +s.deviceId == id;

if(useRedis) {
  unsubscribe = (id, redisSubs) => {

    let findTheSub = findRedisSub.bind(null, id);
    let subscriber = redisSubs.find(findTheSub);

    if(subscriber) {
      subscriber.quit();
      return redisSubs.filter(findTheSub)
    }

    return redisSubs;
  }
}

// can either call if(useRedis) ... inside these functions or use new functions
//  depends if you even need the channels object with redis enabled...?
let isSubscribed = (id, channels) => !Object.keys(channels).includes(id);

let subscribe = (id, channels, ws) => {
  if(isSubscribed(id, channels)) {
    channels[id].push(ws);
  } else {
    channels[id] = [ws];
  }

  if(useRedis) {
    /* add redis sub, return it */
  }
}


/* ... */

//const wss = setUpListener();

// TODO in FP global state is usually a bad thing.
//  Think about where the best place these global states should go...
let channels = {};

// connection function could also be abstracted out...
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  // pull data out
  let id = getId(ws); // function that abstracts details away

  // might return redis, we don't care here
  let subscription = subscribe(id, channels, ws);

  // partially evaluate broadcast with msg and id
  let subscriberBroadcast = broadcast.bind(null, sendMsg, subscription);
  ws.on('message', subscriberBroadcast);
});
```

The connection function code is a lot easier to reason about with this more 'flat' method of thinking about it, and, personally, I like that the abstractions are just plain functions rather than hierarchical objects from a class structure.

Comment: You know... I'm calling somefunc.bind(null, /* other stuff */) a lot, I wonder if people have made that a utilitiy function. [Lodash has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) `_.partial(func, params...)`, but I bet we could get smaller: `const part = (func, ...params) => func.bind(null, params)` then we `part(broadcast, sendMsg, subscription)`. If we wanted to be more expressive we could name it `const partiallyEvaluate` or something.

Comment: This is very interesting... I admit I have not heard of using `bind` for partial evaluation, I've used it to ensure a desired context, but this is quite novel (for me, at least!) I certainly appreciate the flatter structure... I'll have to get my head wrapped around this! Thanks for the effort put into an excellent answer.

Comment: No problem! :) Functional Programming is really a joy once you start flattening things. The first time I realized this was when I started using promises and just passed named functions to it rather than inline.

On one hand, it breaks up the code so you have to scan/search/jump-to-definition a lot to read the code, but on the other hand, if your function names are expressive, it makes the code *much* easier to read, reason about and makes the code communicate more with less.

Comment: @MisterEpic [here is a video from that lovable swedish man](https://youtu.be/GhbhD1HR5vk) that talks about `bind` more in depth.